# reverse timer in jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, timer

I want the jquery or javascript reverse timer where as i need to give only the int as minute to run it : let say i gave 2 mins as input then it should reduce by second per each second but display must be:

01:59 -> tick -> 01:58...and so on. how to achieve this ?

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jquery.timers](http://jquery.offput.ca/timers/).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for a solution like this: [Countdown (JavaScript)](http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2004/10/countdown-javascript.html)

You can get more examples using this Google request: [javascript countdown](http://www.google.com/#q=javascript+countdown)

Comment: Thanks, i gone through these links before . but these links are only date oriented . means it take date as input. i request you please read my question again.I need  based on minute , which takes integer as input , it will convert it in the minute and then run by reducing per second.

Comment: I’ve updated the link. This countdown function allows you to specify the time for the countdown in minutes and seconds.